# What is the correct way to store and access complex related data in a many to many relationship with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10, laravel-eloquent-resource

I have the following database (simplified for demonstration):

- items

  - id
  - name
- milestones

  - id
  - name
- item_milestone

  - id
  - item_id
  - milestone_id
  - completed_at
- files

  - id
  - filename
  - fileable_type
  - fileable_id

I create bunch of items which have milestones and when I loop through those I can easily access data from the item_milestone like 'completed_at'. But if I have a file that is linked to a milestone item via fileable_type = 'App\Models\ItemMilestone' and the record id - how can I access that file record in a loop?

I suppose I could have file_id in the item_milestone table and link back to the file from the item milestone rather than by polymorphic relation, but I'd have the same issue - in a loop I only have access to the pivot data unless I pull it up with another query.

```
@foreach($item->milestones as $milestone)
  {{File::where('fileable_type', 'App\Models\ItemMilestone')->where('fileable_id', $itemmilestone->id)->first()->filename}}
@endforeach
```

I'm using the file model to attach files to all kinds of other models (users, projects, etc) which is why I have a polymorphic relationship. Is there a best practices way to do this - or maybe I'm missing something (which has been known to happen)?!

Answer (score 0):

you have polymorphic relationship between files and other models and your current approach to accessing files in a loop is functional, it can lead to potential performance issues because you are making a separate query for each milestone to retrieve its associated file.

What you can do is use Eager loading to retrieve all the related files in a more efficient way.

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function milestones()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Milestone::class, 'item_milestone', 'item_id', 'milestone_id')
            ->withPivot('completed_at');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Milestone extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'item_milestone', 'milestone_id', 'item_id')
            ->withPivot('completed_at');
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'fileable');
    }
}
```

Query,

```
$item = Item::with('milestones.files')->find($itemId);
```

and then access your data,

```
@foreach($item->milestones as $milestone)
    @foreach($milestone->files as $file)
        {{ $file->filename }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea - good call on the eager loading. In the loop though, the $milestone is a milestone object and the file is linked to the milestoneItem, via the pivot table, so $milestone->files in the second foreach is null. I'm able to access the pivot data, but not a relationship to the pivot resource.

Comment: okay if files are  files are linked to the ItemMilestone through a pivot table, tweek the relationship a little bit.
let me update the code

Comment: I'm still not getting any files in the loop as that inner foreach is still accessing the milestone and the relationship to the file is on the ItemMilestone (which is the pivot table) as it needs to link to both the item and the milestone which are tied to the user (the user's item milestones)

Comment: let me update it again.

Comment: Appreciate the attention on it, but in the loop, it's still outputting milestone->files and the relationship is on the the item_milestone, so still comes up empty. The only way I've found is to run an additional query when the I know the relation exists and a file is linked File::where('fileable_type', 'App\Models\ItemMilestone')->where('fileable_id', $this->pivot->id)->first()

Comment: but this, it will query every time the loop executes, the higher the iterations, the more it will query, that is what we were not doing and we are trying to minimize the queries.

Comment: Very true! Therein lies the problem and the root of my question! Ultimately the file needs to be linked to the pivot table record because it is associated with the Item and Milestone instance. Relationships provide access to pivot data, but not relationships on pivot tables. The loop you suggested in accessing the milestone record which has pivot table values, but does not access a relationship on the pivot table.

Comment: I'm hoping to find a better alternative, but so far, this is my only way to access the file record. Also, the query does not run everytime in the loop, I put a condition to run only when the pivot value is_completed = true, that way it only runs when a file has been attached, which in this project, will be one item milestone per loop.